# Update TableView after deletion animation completes

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, animation

I have a tableview populated with data from an Array of objects.  Objects have a price, name, etc etc.

When a cell is deleted the datasource (Array) is updated and the row slides off screen using UITableViewRowAnimationFade.

When an item is deleted certain properties, such as price, of the objects within the array can change so I therefore need to update all of the cells on screen as their data may have changed.

I've looked over the docs and found *reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation* which I can combine with *indexPathsforVisibleRows* to reload the rows on screen but doing this within tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath looks really nasty since it attempts to perform the deletion animation whilst also reloading...

Is there a way of waiting for the deletion animation to complete before carrying out a task?

Here is the code from my ViewController

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {
        // update the datasource
        [self.dataController deleteItemAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        // update the table
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        // reload the table to show any changes to datasource from above deletion
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }
}
```

asd

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

Ok next try. :) This should definitely work, but it requires quite a bit of effort...

You would need to exactly track the changes in your datasource (add, delete, update) and call the appropriate methods on the TableVC.

The datasource source would need to provide the following delegate methods:

```
- (void)dataControllerWillUpdateData;
- (void)dataControllerDidRemoveObjectAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (void)dataControllerDidAddObjectAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (void)dataControllerDidUpdateObjectAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (void)dataControllerDidUpdateData;
```

Then you change the tableVC's implementation like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {
    // update the datasource
    [self.dataController deleteItemAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}


- (void)dataControllerWillUpdateData
{
    [tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)dataControllerDidRemoveObjectAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}

- (void)dataControllerDidAddObjectAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}

- (void)dataControllerDidUpdateObjectAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
}

- (void)dataControllerDidUpdateData
{
    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

So if the user deletes a cell, your datasource has to determine which other objects are affected, create a list of changes (be careful to calculate the correct indexPaths), call `dataControllerWillUpdateData`, call the appropriate methods above for every changed object and finally call `dataControllerDidUpdateData`.

Of course you could also consider using CoreData in your project. That might require some work to set everything up, but as a result you would get all the above mentioned and much more 'for free'. Personally I tend to use it for almost every project that includes dynamic tableViews. It has so many benefits that it's worth the effort most of the time.

Comment: sorry but that doesn't really help since the Model would still be informing the Controller whilst the deletion animation was taking place resulting in the same thing happening.

Comment: Are the deletions a result of user interaction or of code action?

Comment: If the are the result of a user action (the user taps the 'edit' button, deletes some cells and leaves the edit mode) you could override the tableVC's setEditing:animated:. While the user is editing you track the changes he makes and when the user sets the editing mode to NO (i.e. he taps the edit button again) you update the datasource

Comment: It's a little difficult to answer if we have to guess how your code looks. ;) Could you post your code for the datasource and the tableview delegate methods?

Comment: The deletion is initiated via a swipe on the cell and then carried out via code... updating question with some code now

Comment: that unfortunately throws this error `*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2372/UITableView.m:909`

Comment: a little more effort, will give it a go thanks :)